# JSON support in PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php, json

Is any possible way for JSON support in PHP 5.1.6...?  The JSON feature was very useful in ajax call.  Is any other ways available instead of JSON support in AJAX...?  Can anybody tell me?

Comment: @xdazz I knew already the JSON support available since PHP 5.2 and higher.. But I asked 'Is any possible way in 5.1.6..?'

Comment: So you need the third party lib, like PEAR::JSON etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As xdazz said, you really should update your PHP to plug security holes, but as a quick fix you can download the PEAR module and just include in your file.

http://download.pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON-1.0.3.tgz from this page: http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/download